# Meta-Question: Is it acceptable to ask for recommendation re: MTA & OS combination?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question, asking for recommendation and pro/con about which MTA (e.g., exim & postfix) on what OS (Linux/FreeBSD). Will that be acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison questions luckily haven't been controversial here before (AFAIR), so go ahead.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can ask for software recommendations here (whether amongst a fixed set or not). Just make sure your question states your requirements precisely. “What's the best MTA?” is not a good question (best for what?). “What's a good MTA and OS combination for a server dedicated to relaying and archiving 10k mailing list messages per day?” is a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! Well, I tend to want to know the pro's and con's of them. Helps in justifying my choice to my bosses :)

Comment: That's bass-ackwards, IMO.  Choose your solution based on your needs; don't choose based on personal prejudices and then seek justification.  And remember that, if the company is already accustomed to one OS, introducing another one should only be done for good reason; among other things, if your coworkers already know how to secure the current system(s), bringing in a different one may open you to security issues due to unfamiliarity.  (This includes Unix-likes; Linux's `iptables` and FreeBSD's `pf` are very different beasts.)